# {filedir_X} tag not parsing in File field

Tags: file-uploads, parsing

I have a link to an uploaded PDF in my template but some of links seem to output a mystery {filedir_3} instead of the path to the upload folder.

So the following template code...

```
{if download_details}<a href="{download_details}" target="_blank">Download details &raquo;</a>{/if}
```

outputs as...

```
<a href="{filedir_3}blahblah.pdf" target="_blank">Download details »</a>
```

This seems to be occurring on new files and older uploaded files don't seem to be effected. I had a look at the database and the exp_files table doesn't show any obvious different between working and broken links. I upgraded to EE 2.4.0 recently, could this be the issue? I'm not using MSM and the files aren't being uploaded through RTE or wygwam, just through a file channel field.

Comment: A couple of things: - visit your File Upload Preferences and make sure that the paths and URLs are correct.
- from the same screen (File Upload Preferences), [synchronize your directories](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/content/files/sync_files.html).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but still no luck, the URLs are correct and I tried synchronizing but {filedir_3} is still coming up.

Comment: And what does that field look like in the `exp_channel_data` table?

Comment: First up, what type of field is download_details? Secondly the code shown above, is it within a Channel Entries Tag or is it totally stand-alone as shown above? If we could see a bit more of your code then I think that might help on this one. Best wishes, Mark

Comment: Mark, welcome aboard! Can you move your follow-up questions into comments on the original post rather than present them as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: Oops sorry. Didn't quite know how it all worked here as new to this system. How do I move it now then? Thanks. Also I'm not too sure how you comment instead of placing an answer as when I go to a post then all I have is a text-box at the bottom of the page which says 'Add Another Answer'. I don't see how to add comments to an existing post?

Comment: No problem! I got a few pointers when I started getting active too. If you look at the badges, you can earn some of those by reading through the FAQs & how-tos. The goal is to create topic pages that have thorough questions and options for answers. I'm wondering if you can't comment until your reputation grows? "add comment" is a link under the original question. Maybe something you can go back and tweak later on.

Comment: You beat me to it although only because I couldn't edit my comment above for some reason. I believe it is due to my 'reputation' (whatever that is).

And here's me thinking I used to have a fairly good reputation where ExpressionEngine was concerned.

Comment: Both records look the same in exp_channel_data with the {filedir_3} followed by the pdf name. For example: {filedir_3}Meeting_with_Virginia_Satir.pdf

Comment: Ok, the plot thickens. It appears that the tag is within a custom made plugin with a whole bunch of code. I'm going to dive and and see how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wanted to mention that [parse file paths by Rob Sanchez](https://github.com/rsanchez/parse_file_paths) will parse `{filedir_X}` variables. Usage below:

```
{exp:parse_file_paths}
    {filedir_X}
{/exp:parse_file_paths}
```

To be used with query module, activerecord plugin, and any other add-on that outputs raw channel data.

Since your problem was that a plugin was outputting raw results from the DB, it looks like it would be the perfect fit and would allow you to get rid of that PHP code

Comment: I added an inline code example to this post in the hopes that it helps someone. It is very simple to use.

Comment: @robson-sobral: why did you over-ride/edit my simple inline code example with a bunch of extraneous code???? Your edit does not make any sense? Here is my original edit for future reference:
`{exp:parse_file_paths}{filedir_X}{/exp:parse_file_paths}`

Comment: Just to make clear that you can parse all the content at once, which is faster than one by one. I'm sorry. I gonna bring it back.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I found it was wrapped in a custom plugin which was taking the results directly from the exp_channel_data table. I'm not sure why EE suddenly decided to stop parsing filedir_3 but I added the following if statement into the code as a bit of a bodge and it's working fine now.

```
for($i=0;$i<$data_row_count;$i++) { // for every row
    ..SNIP...
    if (isset($vars['download_details']))
        $vars['download_details'] = str_replace('{filedir_3}','/uploads/',$vars['download_details']);
    $variables[]=$vars;
}
return $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata, $variables) ;
```